# How can i show top 5 most frequently encountered words from the array of "bad words" in user input string

Tags: javascript

I have an array with bad words and function, with find it:

```
let words = textWords.split(' ');
  console.log('words', words)
  let badWords = listOfBadWords.join('|');
  let regex = new RegExp(badWords, 'gi');

  let matches = words.reduce((acc, word) => {
    if (word.match(regex)) {
      let match = word.toLowerCase();
      acc[match] = (acc[match] || 0) + 1;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});

  let sortedMatches = Object.entries(matches).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
  let top5 = sortedMatches.slice(0, 5).map(m => m[0]);

  console.log(sortedMatches, top5); // in format [['word', numberOfUsing], ....]
```

How can i make the output like top 5 words most useable in format: word - numberOfUsing

Comment: Do you mean you want to have a display of the top bad words used by the user? you need data for that.

Comment: Yea, i have an array with bad words, and array with words from user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally wouldn't use regular expression here. I'd create an object to count the words with from the badWords array and simply iterate the user's words to increase the counter. Something like that:

```js
const badWords = ['cunt', 'shit', 'idiot', 'motherfucker', 'asshole', 'dickhead', 'slut', 'prick', 'whore', 'wanker'];
const userText = "I met this idiot today, he did behave like an asshole. This idiot treated me like a slut. Can't believe this idiot made me feeling like a cunt. Such an asshole, really. I tried to speak with this asshole, but he was just a dickhead.";

const counterObject = badWords.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr] = 0;
  return acc;
}, {});

userText.split(/[\s,\.]/).forEach(
  token => {
    if (token in counterObject) counterObject[token]++;
  }
);

const topWords = Object.entries(counterObject).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]).slice(0, 5);

console.log(topWords);
```

Comment: and also how can i take the value( number of using of bad words)

Comment: From your example, i need to take the number ["idiot", 3] - 3

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this

```
const listOfBadWords = ['is', 'or'];
const badWordsFound = [];
const userString = 'This is a test, works or not, is to be seen';

for(i = 0; i < listOfBadWords.length; i++){
    const matches = (userString.match(new RegExp(listOfBadWords[i], 'g')) || []).length;
    if(matches)
        badWordsFound.push([listOfBadWords[i], matches]);
}

const sorted = badWordsFound.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
console.log(sorted);
```